# How to prove a right angle if i have two tangents?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I would appreciate your help, it is long time since I solve trigonometric, like if I have the tangent of angle B equal to $\sqrt{2}-1$ and the tangent of angle C equal to $\sqrt{2}+1$, how can I prove that ABC is right at A using trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

$$\tan(B+C)=\frac{\tan B+\tan C}{1-\tan B\tan C}=\infty$$

Alternatively,

$\tan B\cdot\tan C=\cdots=1\iff\sin B\sin C=\cos B\cos C\iff\cos(B+C)=0$

Answer (score 3):

Recall that 
$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=\cot x =\frac{1}{\tan x}.$$

Now
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+1}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}-1}=\sqrt{2}-1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the statement is true if and only if $ \angle B + \angle C = 90^\circ $. Also, note that $$ \angle B + \angle C = \arctan \left( \sqrt{2} - 1 \right) + \arctan \left( \sqrt{2} + 1 \right). $$Now, we [recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) that $ \arctan b + \arctan c = \arctan \left( \frac {b+c}{1-bc} \right) $.

Using $b=\sqrt{2}-1$ and $c=\sqrt{2}+1$, can you finish from here?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way:

$$\tan B \tan C = \big(\sqrt{2} - 1 \big) \big(\sqrt{2} + 1 \big) = 1$$

And we know that:

$$ \tan B \cot B = 1$$

So it follows that

$$\cot B = \tan C$$

Or

$$ \tan \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - B \right) = \tan C$$